# Delay initialisation of static variables in a 3rd party library

Tags: c++, static, static-libraries, global

I'm linking against a 3rd party library that uses static variables. These end up getting initialised before `main` and grab resources prematurely, causing some havoc in my application. Is there any idiom / technique/ wrapping method, to regain control and define the point in execution where the library is allowed initialise all of its static variables without hacking at the library itself?

Specifically, I have a `thirdpartylib::system` object, that once defined in main, grabs all sorts of resources before main is entered. The compiler sees that the code can be hit, and then goes about initialising all of its static vars out of control of the library consumer. Ideally, I'd like some kind of guard to stop this until I say so, like . .

```
// my code that may exit before I want the lib stuff to be invoked
{
    LET_SYSTEM_RUN_RIOT();
    thirdpartylib::system sys;
    // do some stuff with it
    KILL_IT_ALL_WITH_FIRE();
}
```

Comment: Can the library be dynamically linked, or do they only have a statically linked option?

Comment: I might have misunderstood, but I get the impression that you are defining global variables of the problematic types. Did you try only using local variables in functions? Especially inside `main()` or if necessary in a `{}` block arrived at only later in side `main()` to have some code executed before.

Comment: @Yunnosch no, I'm not defining global vars of the problem types. The problem types depend on globals, so simply allowing the compiler to see that you may want to use one at some point in the execution of your application means that it will initialise all of the globals it depends on before main, and from the top comment, and current answer, looks like I'm gonna be hacking the library source to link statically. Hmph

Comment: @learnvst If you can't build that library as a shared lib, you might consider wrapping the API with your own shared library and do what _@rubenvb_ suggested in their answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you can do is build it dynamically and load it at runtime via dload/LoadLibrary. Then you are in complete control of when the library initializes itself. By linking statically, you are conceptually making the library part of your application, which means it will initialize as part of you application, i.e. before your main function.